# d3 map with nested arrow function use in Grouped Bar Chart Example d3.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to modify this example to my purposes:
https://observablehq.com/@d3/grouped-bar-chart

I was able to do so in Observable and plain Javascript.
However I am using react and typescript in my personal project and do not know how the double arrow function parameter works.

I.e. What does:

```
GroupedBarChart(stateages, {
  x: d => d.state, ....
```

and then:

```
x = (d, i) => i,
const X = d3.map(data, x);
```

here do exactly?

In the first, I select the state attribute of every datapoint

but then of every datapoints datapoint (?) I select the numeric index.

How would I write this concisely without using it as a parameter in the function call?

I've tried `d3.map(data.state, (d, i) => i)` with no luck.

Thanks a lot for any pointers and hints you can give!

Comment: You should post a reproducible example. It does not look like `data.state` would be iterable with map. How about `d3.map(stateages, (d,i) => i )` or  `d3.map(data, (d,i) => i )`

Comment: Hi @SmokeyShakers thanks, the link is the code I want to edit, it works as is. I tried that. They would both work, but not do the same no? Since I want to do the map on the .state column. The example is directly editable: https://observablehq.com/@d3/grouped-bar-chart

Comment: There aren't any actual columns or even tables in the js.  stateages is an array of objects. Each of these objects has a property named state.  You can see that on your link.

Comment: Hi @SmokeyShakers, yes, I apologize I am using bad terminology. So would you be able to explain how this double nesting works? I.e go from d => d.state to (d, i) => i? I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: Sure. If abstractly, each object in the array represents a row of a table. Then each property in an object represents a column in a row.   Table-to-Row-to-Column is like Array-to-Object-to-Property. Its a hierarchy. You can't refer to a property without it's object, so you can't refer to a column without its row. `map` is a function that says go through each object in the array (each row of the table, so to speak). Then what? `d => d.state` means return the value of `state`. You don't want that. Just the row number. There's not need to specify any property (column).

Comment: Oh @SmokeyShakers thank you so much, I think I understand now and even have an idea on how I could probably write this into one line. Thanks!!

Comment: Hmm, ok no that (I tried more direct nesting) didn't work, but I'm on track I think.